# How to kill the ubuntuone daemon?

Tags: ubuntu-one, kill

The ubuntuone daemon is eating 100% of my CPU. I contacted the ubuntuone support but while they are looking for a solution, I'd like to kill it so it doesn't disturb my work.

I can't kill -9 it, as it will respawn imidiatly under a new PID.

I did removed it from my start up app settings, but it's still running at start up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try killing the daemon with the following:

```
sudo killall -9 ubuntuone-syncdaemon
```

To start it again try

```
python /usr/lib/ubuntuone-client/ubuntuone-syncdaemon &
```

Comment: Sweet, it works. But what does it does that kill -9 doesn't?

Comment: 'kill' stops one process.  'killall' stops all named processes - i.e. in this case, the daemon and any spawned child processes with the same name.

Answer (score 5):

You can open the Ubuntu One Control Panel and disable file synchronization completely from the “Services” tab:

[image: Ubuntu One Control Panel's services' tab]

If you're using an earlier version of Ubuntu you have the same functionality exposed in Ubuntu One Preferences:

[image: Ubuntu One Preferences' Services tab]

Comment: +1. Kept the other one accepted because the question was about "to kill" the daemon that I was enable to kill. But your answer is cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use Ubuntu One (Canonical's cloud service), you can just get rid of the entire suite by typing the following into the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntuone-client
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need ubuntuone you can uninstall the `ubuntuone-syncdaemon` package.

Comment: I do want ubuntuone to stay. I'm waiting for the support to find the solution so I can use it again. I don't want to uninstall it, just disable it in the meantime. This way, I can run my sync by night when I'm not using the computer.